# How to Check if a Datetime with Timezone already in Past

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have this Javascript Array of Objects:

```
var schedule = [
        {"Date":"2016/08/29","Time":"02:15","GameNumber":"1","Game":"Red vs Blue"},
        {"Date":"2016/09/11","Time":"02:30","GameNumber":"2","Game":"Red vs White"}
    ]
```

What I want is to check whether the `Date,Time with Timezone` already in the past and delete it in the array of objects. I'm thinking to use moment.js but I'm not sure whether it can.

Any pointers or solutions on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with Timezone? I do not see any reference to it in your array

Comment: For Example my timezone is in UTC+08:00

Comment: Parse the date and compare it to `Date.now()`, eg `parsedDate < Date.now()`

Comment: @Phil I will use moment.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
schedule.forEach(function(node){
    var date = new Date(node.Date+" "+node.Time+":00"); 
    var now = new Date(); 
    if(now>date){
             console.log("Time passed");
    } 
});
```

Comment: I think this will not consider timezone?

Comment: use new Date(schedule[0].Date+" "+schedule[0].Time+":00")